# Passing PHP variable to Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, php

i want to pass  PHP variable to Javascript array.
It is a test code, but in further i want to pass  the printed product id's and name's to this ajax function  to send it to cart
The code above is working  without printing the button with echo.Any better ideas are welcome :)

```
 <html>

<?php 

$num=3;

echo "<button onclick='funkt('<?php echo $num ?>');'>cc</button>
";

?>
</html>
<script>

function funkt(x){
 var c=x;
alert(c);
}



</script>
```

Comment: You can't `echo` inside an `echo`.

Comment: And I wouldn't opt to `echo` the button anyway. Separating php and html in mixed code makes it more readable (reduces the number of quotes as well as quoting issues that come along with it).

Comment: PHP runs on the server, before the page is sent to the browser.  PHP code can't run in the browser.

Comment: @codemaster96 check out my answer please

Comment: Could you edit the question so that it is clear what you are asking? What js array? What ajax? There is nothing like that in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't properly escaping the quotes inside the echo statement. Also, HTML attributes use double quotes (onclick="..."), not single quotes.
Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
<script>
    function funkt(x) {
        var c = x;
        alert(c);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$num = 3;
echo "<button onclick=\"funkt('" . $num . "');\">cc</button>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes you are right!:) Thank you for the help, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Better option is to add an input field of type [hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden) and pass the number/name/ID to it. On submission of form or button click, you can fetch it wtih the field Id and pass the value to ajax.

```
<input type="hidden" id="number" value="<?php echo $num;?>" />


<script>
    function funkt(x) {
        var c = document.querySelector("#number").value;
        alert(c);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes its okay, but this method don't work when im printing the products on the web site, because i  need the information about the product where i click,  but anyway thank you for help :))!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to declare variable inside "script" tag, and then use this variable in the javascript afterwards like this:

```
<?php  $num = 5;  ?>   
    <script>
          var link_label = '<?php echo $num ?>';

          //use your link_label value to load it in ajax here or in other files that has been loaded after this script

    </script>
```